# Using the phonegap framework with node.js, javascript, html, mysql and css

Tags: html, node.js, cordova

Can someone please show me an example of how we use phonegap and node.js to push and pull data  to mySQL database from an html page/form .

THANKS

**EDIT**

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ host : 'localhost', user : 'root', database :'nodejsmysql', password : '' });
connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT * from nodejs', function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].fname); }
);
connection.end();
```

I have the above code which works very well, But I dont want to display my results on the console, instead I want to display them on an html textBox

Comment: Did you try something that didn't work? If yes please show it, otherwise I believe your question is too broad.

Comment: var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : 'localhost',
user : 'root',
database :'nodejsmysql',
password : ''
});
connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT * from nodejs', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

 console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].fname);
});
connection.end();      

i have the above code which works very well, But i dont want to display my results on the console, instead i want to display them on an html textBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app     = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : 'localhost',
user : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'nodejsmysql'
});

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/index', function(req, res) {

var date = req.body.date;

 connection.query('INSERT INTO reservations(Date) VALUES (? );' , [date], function(err,       docs) {
if (err) res.json(err);
res.redirect('users');
});
});
```

I managed to nail it using this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use custom web service to communicate with your server. You cannot directly manipulate the data on client side. The data manipulation happen only at server side. So, either you will use REST or SOAP, it's up to you how you want to implement it. I suggest you doing more research about the web service.

- REST - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
- SOAP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

More

- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
- http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/25/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-2/

Comment: Don't you have a link reference which can show me examples done in Node.js?